# How to create a map thumbnail with marker like location sharing in whatsapp

Tags: java, android, location, maps, chat

i am developing a chat application, Please suggest me any idea to create a map thumbnail of a location For sharing person's location to another person in chat page, like the location sharing in whatsApp.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: back in google-maps-api1 you used to be able to get the map as a bitmap from the api, then api2 came out and you couldnt anymore so i used google-static-maps-api to get a picture of the map, but new map api 3 came out so maybe they put that functionality back in, idk but you can use google static maps api to download a map you specify the coordinates and use that

Comment: Thanks @JRowan google static maps api works great!!, thanks for sharing.

Comment: your welcome, ill post that comment as an answer if that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

back in google-maps-api1 you used to be able to get the map as a bitmap from the api, then api2 came out and you couldnt anymore so i used google-static-maps-api to get a picture of the map, but new map api 3 came out so maybe they put that functionality back in, idk but you can use google static maps api to download a map you specify the coordinates and use that